# That seemed odd. Then came yelping, nearer still. (what does this mean?)

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

> The faraway yipping was joined by nearer yapping. A couple of dogs? That seemed odd. Then came yelping, nearer still. Then howling. I froze. The hairs on the back of my neck stood up.

nearer is adverb and still is also adverb? what does this mean?

Comment: The adverb _still_ is being used in the sense of _even_. The yelping sounded even nearer to the narrator than the yapping had done.

Answer (score 3):

This particular use of 'still' means *to an even greater degree or in an even greater amount*.

One example of this usage from Cambridge dictionary is:

> I'm worried that his car has broken down, or worse still, that he's had an accident.

So, the car breaking down is bad, but an accident is *worse still* - meaning it is bad to a greater degree than the first thing stated.

Your example speaks first about "faraway yipping". Then, "nearer yapping". Finally, it says "yelping, nearer still". It is showing that each noise is closer than the last.